# WPF ComboboxItems with button

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I have created my own combobox style along with stylign combobox items. The dropdown needs to display some items with buttons and others without my items are created dynamically as follows:

```
            ComboBoxItem typeItem = new ComboBoxItem();
            typeItem.Content = "Test";
            typeItem.Tag = i;
            MyCombobox.Items.Add(typeItem);
```

My question is how do I apply this style to some items and not others, my two comboboxitems are bellow?

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MinimumIteractSizeDips}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MinimumIteractSizeDips}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyComboBoxItem" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MinimumIteractSizeDips}" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=MinimumIteractSizeDips}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="Black" Background="White" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="Settings" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2" Name="PositionSettings" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="57"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [StyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector.aspx) class.

```
public class MyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
     public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var element = container as FrameworkElement;
        var myVm = item as MyViewModel;

        if(myVm.EditMode)
            return element.FindResource("TemplateWithButtons") as DataTemplate
        return element.FindResource("TemplateNormal") as DataTemplate

    }
}
```

and in xaml, define a resource for your selector

```
<MyStyleSelector x:Key="myStyleSelector"/>
```

and apply that to your combobox.

```
<ComboBox StyleSelector="{StaticResource myStyleSelector}"/>
```

btw. x:Key with the same type as `TargetType` is redundant.

Final Note: You should not override the style for that. What you want is DataTemplate and the DataTemplate selector. Also you should not bind the Content(type object) to a labels text (type string), a ContentPresenter is the way to go here.

Comment: #dowhilefor many thanks I managed to get it to display the correct style. What did you mean by "You should not override the style for that. What you want is DataTemplate and the DataTemplate selector". Am i going about adding the buttons the worng way?

Comment: A control like a ComboBoxItem is split into two parts, one the Control itself, defined by its Style, is responsible for a general look and feel of your application, how selection works, keyboard navigation etc.. The Content of it, defined by a DataTemplate is what is displayed inside the ComboBoxItem, its Business data so to speak. Unless you want to greatly redefine your style, i wouldn't touch it. But even then, i would consider to keep the style "business logic" free and use the Content and DataTemplates for that. Also remember to mark the answer that helped you as accepted.